# Show SQL Query Result Using wxPython

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to get the result from the SQL Query to show up next to the text "Tickets Closed Last 24 Hours" when the script is executed.
The SQL Query returns a single number. 
I am trying to get the number to show in the StaticText box for self.some_text where it changes the label text to the number when ran.

Example: https://s11.postimg.org/jil0kzfqb/tickets.png
In the image there is no number from the SQL query.
(You can ignore the Address, unit number and city text and boxes)

I am going off another program someone else created so some of this code may not be needed.
I am trying to learn SQL and Python on the fly, pretty much a novice right now.

This is my code so far:

```
import wx
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxxxxxxxxxxx",port=xxx,user="xx",passwd="xxxxx",db="xxxx")

class Data():
    def TicketsClosedLast24Hours(self, event):
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute("Select COUNT(*) FROM HD_TICKET WHERE HD_STATUS_ID = 12 AND TIME_CLOSED >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY")
        row = cur.fetchone()
        print(row[0])
        row = cur.fetchone()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        self.Centre()
        self.Maximize(True)

        self.background = wx.Panel(self)
        self.background.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(98, 125, 152))

        self.some_text = wx.StaticText(self.background, wx.ID_ANY, label="", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.Address = wx.TextCtrl(self.background, -1, "", size=(140, -1))
        self.UnitNumber = wx.TextCtrl(self.background, -1, "", size=(140, -1))
        self.City = wx.TextCtrl(self.background, -1, "", size=(140, -1))

        self.horizontalRow0 = wx.BoxSizer()
        img1 = wx.Image("logo1.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP, -1)
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.background, -1, wx.BitmapFromImage(img1), (55, 0))
        self.horizontalRow0.Add(self.bitmap1, wx.Center, border=10)

        self.VerticalRow1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.VerticalRow1.Add(wx.StaticText(self.background, -1, "Tickets Closed Last 24 Hours",
                                            style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER), flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.VerticalRow1.Add(wx.StaticText(self.background, -1, "Address:",
                                            style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER), flag=wx.ALL, border=9)
        self.VerticalRow1.Add(wx.StaticText(self.background, -1, "Unit Number:",
                                            style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER), flag=wx.ALL, border=9)
        self.VerticalRow1.Add(wx.StaticText(self.background, -1, "City:",
                                            style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER), flag=wx.ALL, border=9)

        # To add labels - H-1 V-2
        self.VerticalRow2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.VerticalRow2.Add(self.some_text, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=6)
        self.VerticalRow2.Add(self.Address, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=6)
        self.VerticalRow2.Add(self.UnitNumber, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=6)
        self.VerticalRow2.Add(self.City, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=6)

        # Combine V-1 And V-2 to H1
        self.horizontalRow1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.horizontalRow1.Add((30, 30), proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        self.horizontalRow1.Add(self.VerticalRow1, proportion=.5)
        self.horizontalRow1.Add(self.VerticalRow2, proportion=0)

        # To add labels - H-3 V-8
        self.VerticalRow1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # To add labels - H-4 V-9
        self.horizontalRow4 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.horizontalRow4.Add((30, 30), proportion=.5, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        self.horizontalRow4.Add((30, 30), proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)

        # Adds horizontal Rows to Main Window in Vertical boxes
        self.verticalBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.verticalBox.Add(self.horizontalRow0, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        self.verticalBox.Add((10, 10), proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        self.verticalBox.Add(self.horizontalRow1, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        self.verticalBox.Add((10, 10), proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        self.verticalBox.Add(self.horizontalRow4, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)

        self.background.SetSizer(self.verticalBox)
        self.Show()

    def someFunction(self):
        mysql_data = databasemodel.returnData()  # query your database to return a string
        self.some_text.SetLabel(mysql_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    window = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am trying to get the result from the SQL Query to show up next to the text "Tickets Closed Last 24 Hours" when the script is executed.   The SQL Query returns a single number. I am trying to get the number to show in the StaticText box for self.some_text where it changes the label text to the number when ran. 
https://s11.postimg.org/jil0kzfqb/tickets.png
In the image there is no number from the SQL query.
(You can ignore the Address, unit number and city text and boxes)

Comment: I suggest you edit the question so it will be clearer to everyone what exactly you are asking. It would be best if the title will also reflect the essence of the question.

Comment: Thanks, made a few edits that will hopefully explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct to me. I don't see anything that is actually calling `someFunction` though. My guess is that that is the issue. You should try calling that and printing out `mysql_data` to stdout to make sure the result you are receiving is what you expect.